# Update rows then Insert new associated rows, or restructure data?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

Let's set the stage, PHP & MYSQL:

I have a table we'll call *Directions* to hold each step for a given task. Each task has variable steps.

The only real essential fields for this question are (primary) **step_id**,**task_id**, **step**.

When the author updates their directions, they can update each step, add new ones, remove old ones.

I understand how to handle the updating / insertion / deleting logic structure 
`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` and so on.

My concern lies elsewhere. Say someone writes directions for task #1, five months later they update task #1 with a few new steps. In that time, there are 1000 new tasks.

Is it really an issue that the majority of steps for task #1 will be located in say... step_id 1-10, and that new step will be way down in 10001?

Since I run no specific computations on the steps, is this a situation where I'm better off storing each step as a serialized array in a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe task_id is quite essential field for this question too. If it is indexed you won't have any performance issues with selecting steps for a given task no matter how separated they are in your table.

With steps serialized you would have more issues as you would have to deserialize them for every update/delete, serialize again and then update the row, also you could run into problems with column size unless you limit number of steps for every task.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was plugging dummy data into the database and watching how it evolved. Once I multiplied the scope of interactions over a large scale, I began to get concerned. More of a "hand holding" type question.